# How to assign value to text input from viewbag when viewbag contains value passed from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

Im new to ASP.NET MVC3.

I tried to pass value from controller to a view and then assign that value to text input inside the view.

I tried with viewbag and viewdata. While debugging i could find the value inside viewbag but when my view appers in the browser, textbox is empty.

However , if i assign some value to viewbag from within .cshtml file, it work.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
 ViewBag.fullname = "Hello";
 ........
 return view();
}
```

**View**

```
@{ ViewBag.lastname = "Hello";
}
@Html.TextBox("fullname", (string)ViewBag.fullname)
@Html.TextBox("lastname", (string)ViewBag.lastname)
```

**output**

first textbox - empty

second textbox - Hello

Comment: to start with using Viewbag,  you might want to check [this](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-pass-values-from-controller-to-view-using-viewbag-in-mvc-3/) out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out...

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
 ViewBag.fullname = "Hello";
 ViewBag.lastname = "World";

 return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.TextBox("fullname", (string)ViewBag.fullname)
@Html.TextBox("lastname", (string)ViewBag.lastname)
```

Also check [this](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-pass-values-from-controller-to-view-using-viewbag-in-mvc-3/)

Comment: thanks for response dude. This is exactly what i did but its not working for me. Are you sure this works for you?